# GAEのFWで弾かれた際の403ページのカスタマイズ

Tags: google-app-engine

GAE上でstatic_fileとして置いているhtmlがあるのですが、
特定のIPアドレス以外からアクセスされた場合は見れないようにしたいと思っています。
GAEの機能としてFWがあるのでこちらで実現しようと思ったのですが
FWで弾かれた際にはgoogleが用意している403ページが表示されます。

このページを自分用にカスタマイズしたいのですが可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806997/

現時点では方法はないとのことでした。
(app.yamlまで到達しないのでerror_handlersでも対応できません。)

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref

app.yaml に error_handlers というディレクティブがあります。もしかしたら、これを使えば指定したページを表示できるかもしれません。

FWとの組み合わせは、私自身は未確認です。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806997/ app.yamlまで到達しないとこのことです。